# Laravel 5 eager loading dropping leading zeros from foreign key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3, leading-zero

I believe that I've encountered a bug in how Laravel 5.3 handles eager loading when the foreign key is a string which contains zerofilled numbers.

I have two models (using a mysql backend), `School` and `Student`.  The `id` field in `School` is a string, and contains 5-digit numbers assigned by the state, which include leading zeros.  `Student` `BelongsTo` `School`, and contains a `school_id` field which is defined identically to the `id` field in `School`.  I have done some testing, and I'm finding that when I call `Student::with('school')` I get the expected `School` models as long as the `school_id` in `Student` is free of leading zeroes, but it returns no `School` models for `school_id` values with leading zeroes.

I've done direct testing with freshly minted `School` records, and the values are being stored correctly with leading zeroes in both database tables, and when I try directly querying the tables the leading zeroes work fine, but as soon as `with()` enters the equation, things break.  I've attempted to reproduce the failure through other means, even manually constructing `whereIn()` calls to mirror syntax of the queries constructed by `with()`, but everything else correctly returns the expected records.

This code worked fine prior to climbing the Laravel upgrade ladder from 4.1 to 5.3, so I'm wondering what may have changed.  I've gone as far as digging into [the GitHub repository for BelongsTo](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsTo.php), and none of the parameter handling seems to strip leading zeroes, so I'm really at a loss as to why `with()` is breaking in this way.

So, does anybody have any insights they can share?  I'm stumped, and would rather not have to engineer around `with()`.  I'll also state up front that I can't drop the leading zeroes from the `id` field, it's not an option, they must actually be stored, and not just displayed as with ZEROFILL.

UPDATE:  I've attached an example that establishes that the `school_id` stored in `Student` can successfully connect to the corresponding `School` when used separately from the `with()` statement:

```
    $interventions = Intervention::with('school')->where('id','=',780)->get();
    $schools = School::whereIn('id',$interventions->pluck('school_id')->all())->get();
    throw new \Exception(print_r($interventions,true).'|'.print_r($schools,true));
```

Here are the (edited for brevity) results of the \Exception:

```
Exception in AdminController.php line 273:
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => App\Models\Student Object
        (
            [attributes:protected] => Array
            (
                [id] => 780
                [school_id] => 01234
            )
            [relations:protected] => Array
            (
                [school] => 
            )
        )
    )
)


Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => App\Models\School Object
        (
            [attributes:protected] => Array
            (
                [id] => 01234
                [school] => Test1
                [district_id] => 81000
                [inactive] => 0
                [see] => 0
            )
        )
    )
)
```

So, while `Student::with('school')` fails to pull up the corresponding `School`, feeding the same `Student->school_id` values to `School::whereIn()` succeeds.  I remain mystified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not showing the model classes, but my guess is you need `public $incrementing = false;` in the `School` Eloquent model. Otherwise it will be coerced to int when matching the relationship, losing all leading zeroes.

Comment: Ooh, that is >good<!  I had a feeling there was something going on specifically with the matching, since the query syntax seemed to be returning the correct records.  I will do some testing and report back.

Comment: Yep, that did it!  I'm pretty sure that back when I first built this under Laravel 4.1 that it wasn't mentioned, but I could be wrong.  Thanks for the response.